# Anonymous android.view.View.OnLongClickListener

Tags: android

```
Hbutton.setOnClickListener(
    new Button.OnLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onLongClick(View v){
            TextView Htext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Htext);
            Htext.setText("Hunny");
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

whats wrong in this code??
it gives an ERROR

```
(anonymous android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)
```

Comment: Hbutton have you init in your file like findviewbyid ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set onLongClickListener :

```
Hbutton.setOnLongClickListener(
        new Button.OnLongClickListener(){
             public boolean onLongClick(View v){
                TextView Htext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Htext);
                Htext.setText("Hunny");
                return true;
            }
        }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
Button Hbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

Hbutton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //do your stuff here

            return true;
        }
    });
```